# How to write a blob to a file in Chrome apps?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome app which can download videos from server, save it locally and display it when user wants to. I am able to get the blob using xhr from server, but I do not know how to write it to a file, I am using Chrome.file system api. No luck. Any links to tutorials on using file write api ?

Comment: html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [fileSystem API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem)

[Chrome Dev Editor](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chromedeveditor) uses it.

Comment: Stack at similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34531428/chrome-apps-how-to-save-blob-content-to-filesystem-in-the-background

`chrome.fileSystem.requestFileSystem` method is only supported in Kiosk apps.

chooseEntry method requests user to choose a directory/file.