# Chrome Apps : How to save blob content to fileSystem in the background?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, html5-filesystem

In Chrome Apps, I'm downloading a blob content from a server using JavaScript XHR (Angular $http GET in particular, with response type 'blob')

How should I save this to chrome application's file system?

Currently using an Angular wrapper on HTML5 filesystem API
https://github.com/maciel310/angular-filesystem

I do not want to show user a popup (hence I can't use `chrome.fileSystem. chooseEntry` )

The `chrome.fileSystem.requestFileSystem` API is only supported by Kiosk-only apps.
Hence I'm using HTML5 FileSystem API instead of chrome's.

I'm using following code to make XHR to fetch blob.

```
 $http({
          url: SERVER_URL+"/someVideo.mp4",
          method: "GET",
          responseType: "blob"
      }).then(function(response) {
          console.log(response);
          fileSystem.writeBlob(response.name, response).then(function() {
             console.log("file saved");
          }, function(err) {
              console.log(err);
          });
      }, function (response) {

      });
```

This is my writeBlob method

```
writeBlob: function(fileName, blob, append) {
    append = (typeof append == 'undefined' ? false : append);

    var def = $q.defer();

    fsDefer.promise.then(function(fs) {

        fs.root.getFile(fileName, {create: true}, function(fileEntry) {

            fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {
                if(append) {
                    fileWriter.seek(fileWriter.length);
                }

                var truncated = false;
                fileWriter.onwriteend = function(e) {
                    //truncate all data after current position
                    if (!truncated) {
                        truncated = true;
                        this.truncate(this.position);
                        return;
                    }
                    safeResolve(def, "");
                };

                fileWriter.onerror = function(e) {
                    safeReject(def, {text: 'Write failed', obj: e});
                };

                fileWriter.write(blob);

            }, function(e) {
                safeReject(def, {text: "Error creating file", obj: e});
            });

        }, function(e) {
            safeReject(def, {text: "Error getting file", obj: e});
        });

    }, function(err) {
        def.reject(err);
    });

    return def.promise;
},
```

This shows `SECURITY_ERR` as `It was determined that certain files are unsafe for access within a Web application, or that too many calls are being made on file resources.`

What's the solution for this?

I've tried using `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag while launching app. It doesn't help.

Comment: When you say you don't want to show a popup.html do you just mean you don't want a popup to occur? Meaning you need the script to run from the tab being viewed on a click method?

Comment: I mean the video should be saved automatically in the background. it shouldn't prompt user where to save,which happens with choosEntry mefhod

Comment: did you accept the answer from the other question as n answer?

Comment: Do you have a match pattern giving you host permissions for SERVER_URL in the 'permissions' field of your manifest? (I can't recall off the top of my head if this is relevant for apps or not; it likely would be for an extension)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chrome Application's sandbox storage doesn't allow files to be stored in root directory (i.e. `/` )

Modify the code to save it in a specific sub-directory under it.
For example -

```
fileSystem.writeBlob("/new"+response.name, response).then(function() {
             console.log("file saved");
          }, function(err) {
              console.log(err);
          });
```

This would successfully save the file under `/new/` directory.

Comment: Is that documented anywhere?

Comment: @Xan Unfortunately not!
I found this on a forum https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-apps/j4f48wn-pBE (read Joe Marini's reply - second line)

Comment: Um, wrong topic maybe? Package directory entry is fully read-only.

Comment: hmm.. yes. So this isn't documented anywhere to my knowledge.

Comment: @Xan reported! https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=578358&thanks=578358&ts=1452928673

Comment: Er, did you report that as a security bug? It really isn't, despite the error :)

Comment: @Xan couldn't find anything such as 'documentation' topic!

Comment: There isn't really (and I did report that a long time ago), without ability to set labels you can only try to explain it in the report. But you will mildly annoy the security team now.

Comment: do you have to create the directory first? I'm getting this error `DOMException: A requested file or directory could not be found at the time an operation was processed`

Answer (score 1):

To expand on this, here is a full example app on how to download a file and save the blob and display it back to the user.

https://github.com/PierBover/chrome-os-app-download-example