# How to download a file on a Chrome packaged app?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

When looking at downloading a file I always end up at [the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads) for `chrome.downloads` API, but this is only available for extensions and not packaged apps.

So how can I download a file in a Chrome packaged app?

Comment: Define "download". Do you want to give it to users or use it internally?

Comment: Use it internally, and maybe later show it to the user.

Comment: There's a bug report on this. Looks like one of the users found a hacky way to get it to work with an iframe - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=821219

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation for [Referencing external resources](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external#external).

In short, the recommendation is to save downloaded resources (e.g. images) as `blob:` URLs that you can store in any of the [Storage APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_apps#saving-locally).

Comment: For anyone trying to figure this out check this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34531428/chrome-apps-how-to-save-blob-content-to-filesystem-in-the-background

Comment: I made this repo with an example app: https://github.com/PierBover/chrome-os-app-download-example